# What am i missing with this formula can you help to expand it?

Tags: excel

Morning All,

Ive been working a on a spreadsheet and it came back with some requests to refine and simplify it, as such iv come up with a new solution but the below formula i cant for the life of me figure out why its bringing back the #Value Error.

```
=IF(L6="YES",K6+7,IF(L6,"-",""))
```

In a nut shell i want this formula to do the following,

IF L6 is Yes then calculate K6+7 If L6 is blank then leave it blank and dont calculate

Firstly am i on the right lines here and if so what on earth am i missing? Im still getting my excel knowledge up at the moment so bear with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `L6` is blank then you don't need the dash (i.e. "-")? And if it does have a dash then you want: `...IF(L6="-","")`.

Comment: I knew it was something so simple, thanks for your help Alex, could you post this as an answer and ill mark it as solved. Thanks again,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `=` in the second `IF` formula:

```
=IF(L6="YES",K6+7,IF(L6="",""))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and iv been able to adapt it slightly more as well 

```
=IF(L6="YES",K6+7,IF(L6="-","-",""))
```
So now the cell will return a - if one is found but if not it leaves it blank. Thanks so much for you help Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula should look like this

```
=IF(L6="YES",K6+7,IF(isblank(L6),,"-"))
```

The value error was due to the fact a blank cell is considered as false by default but a cell with text cannot be converted to a boolean value.